# How to run DNS Server (dnsmasq) in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, dnsmasq

I'm trying to run DNS Server (Dnsmasq) in Kubernetes cluster. The cluster has only one node. Everything works fine until I need to restart dnsmasq container (`kubectl rollout restart daemonsets dnsmasq-daemonset`) to apply changes made to `hosts` ConfigMap. As I found out this is needed as Dnsmasq that is already running will not otherwise load changes made into `hosts` ConfigMap.

Soon as the container is restarted it is not able to pull dnsmasq image and it fails. It is expected behavior as it cannot resolve the image name as there are no other dns servers running, but I wonder what would be best way around it or what are the best practices with running DNS Server in Kubernetes in general. Is this something that CoreDNS is used for or what other alternatives are there? Maybe some high availability solution?

hosts ConfigMap:

```
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: dnsmasq-hosts
  namespace: core
data:
  hosts: |
    127.0.0.1       localhost

    10.x.x.x        example.com
    ...
```

Dnsmasq deployment:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: dnsmasq-daemonset
  namespace: core
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dnsmasq-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dnsmasq-app
      namespace: core
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dnsmasq
          image: registry.gitlab.com/path/to/dnsmasqImage:tag
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: "32Mi"
            requests:
              cpu: "150m"
              memory: "16Mi"
          ports:
            - name: dns
              containerPort: 53
              hostPort: 53
              protocol: UDP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: conf-dnsmasq
              mountPath: /etc/dnsmasq.conf
              subPath: dnsmasq.conf
              readOnly: true
            - name: dnsconf-dnsmasq
              mountPath: /etc/dnsmasq.d/dns.conf
              subPath: dns.conf
              readOnly: true
            - name: hosts-dnsmasq
              mountPath: /etc/dnsmasq.d/hosts
              subPath: hosts
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: conf-dnsmasq
          configMap:
            name: dnsmasq-conf
        - name: dnsconf-dnsmasq
          configMap: 
            name: dnsmasq-dnsconf
        - name: hosts-dnsmasq
          configMap:
            name: dnsmasq-hosts
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-registry-credentials
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: master
      restartPolicy: Always
```

I tried to use `imagePullPolicy: Never`, but it seems to fail anyway.

Comment: Kubernetes [provides its own DNS system](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) that your cluster administrator should have installed when they created the cluster.  You don't need to install a DNS layer on top of it.

Comment: hi @JohnyFailLab, does David's comment solves your issue?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for feedback. I wasn't probably clear enough, but I'm need a DNS Server that resolves external requests. Not requests only within the cluster. From what I understand the DNS system in Kubernetes - kube-dns & core-dns is used mostly only for resolving dns requests within the kubernetes cluster. Not sure if I'm right though. I need all dns requests within my LAN network to be resolved by that dns server.

Comment: @JohnyFailLab, did u get this to work with dnsmasq or another DNS like bind as I want to try exactly the same thing which is not to run a DNS for my cluster but rather to run a DNS server on top of my cluster to be used as a DNS for some domains that are unrelated, like I would do running a dns on a VM, which is if I understood correctly what you were trying to do as well?